# Qt: Using thread to construct widgets

Tags: multithreading, qt, qwidget

In my Application, I have a `QWidget MyWidget` which I need to construct after a PushButton click. Now, MyWidget is a heavy widget with many children components and those children components have many components too. Now, when I try to construct the widget after the push button press, it takes sometimes for the widget to appear, which I don't like. So, I need to construct the widget before the PushButton clicked and keep an instance ready at hand. Thread seems perfect for this job. But I have little idea about Qt Thread.

Now can somebody suggest me how to approach the problem and what can be done to solve the problem?

Note:
To say explicitly why is my widget so heavy, in MyWidget, I have 7*24 widgets, each having a stacked Widget with two widgets stacked on it each having a button.

Comment: Are those children components your own widgets? What takes so long in their initialization? Why do you do this initialization in the constructors?

Comment: What alternative idea can I use?

Comment: You have to show the code at this point. Code that we can compile and test. Code that reproduces your "slowness"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Qt does not support creation of widgets in non-gui threads. The reason is simple: widget constructors are free to access thread-unsafe APIs that can be used by the main thread at any time. Thus even if it might appear to work, it's really a bug in your code if you do it.

Generally speaking, in your heavyweight widget classes, parallelize the non-graphical, long-running initialization tasks. You can use `QtConcurrent::run` for this purpose. Of course you need to make your implementation thread-safe for this purpose.

You must also ensure that you absolutely, positively *don't* use any blocking APIs in your widget code. No GUI code generally, but no widget constructor specifically, should ever:

- wait for any file accesses to finish,
- wait for any networking to finish,
- wait for any database access to finish,
- use any `waitForXxxx` methods in Qt,
- use things that may indirectly access the file system, such as `QSettings`.

Comment: If you are telling me to make the ui constructor thread safe, I have made it thread safe. Later on, the ui calls some controller classes, the constructor classes on behalf the controller accesses the database. Is it good enough?

Comment: @ShakibAhmed A `QWidget` constructor by definition is not thread safe, you can't "make it" so. What you need to make thread safe is the long-running code that does the non-graphical initialization that presumably runs long. Such code can then be executed through `QtConcurrent::run` - it will run in a worker thread. You'd need to tell us what's taking so long in your constructors.

Comment: To say explicitly, in my widget, I have 7*24 widgets, each having a stacked Widget with two widgets stacked on it each having a button.

Comment: @ShakibAhmed Great. Show us a simple example of a `main` function that creates this, ideally with some timing code to show the timing of it. It should be no more than I think 40 lines in total. Otherwise this discussion is in a vacuum.

Answer (score 1):

First of all Qt and pretty much every other framework (at last those that I know) that deals with UI elements have very specifics requirements for multi-thread support.

Qt needs every `QObject` descendant (like `QWidget`) to be assigned to a thread (see [QObject::thread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#thread)).

This property is automatically assigned on object creation to the thread where the object is being created.

The problem with this is that Qt also requires that a widget receive events only if it belongs to the same thread where the event loop is running (and it is correctly added to a parent widget).

If you are creating you huge widget at some different thread, it will not receive events until it is moved to the thread with the event loop and re-parented.

You can move the `QWidget` to another thread by calling the [QObject::moveToThread()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#moveToThread) method. Suppose `mParent` is your `QMainWindow` and `mMyWidget` is your huge widget:

```
mMyWidget->setParent(0);
mMyWidget->moveToThread(mParent->thread());
mMyWidget->setParent(mParent); // change this to match your layout requirements.
```

Check [QWidget::setParent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#setParent) for more info.

The creation of your huge widget should be performed not at the same thread as your main thread. This is left as an exercise, since it is pretty much straight forward and Qt docs are extensive on threads.

Take care if your button is pressed before the creation of the widget is completed: you must synchronize the access to variable to avoid undefined behavior.

This is a very high level look at the problem, but is a start, and since you did not provide any code, I'm giving you a minimum ;D

Another option (and probably a better one) is to look why your widget is so time consuming to create, but without more information I can not help.

Comment: I think you're assuming a whole lot when you suggest it's not undefined behavior to instantiate a `QWidget` in another thread. As far as I'm concerned, any attempt to do so is a bug that will bite you sooner or later. If your widget instantiation takes so much time, you're supposed to relegate the time-consuming, non-gui things to a helper that is executed through `QtConcurrent::run`. That's the best you can do. Of course some graphical things can be done from any thread. For example, painting or loading `QImage`s.

Comment: I'd love to be wrong here, of course. Please show some corroboration (documentation or relevant analysis of Qt source code) that would indicate that creating widgets on a random thread is OK.

Comment: At the moment, I treat this answer as **seriously bad advice**.

Comment: When I started learning Qt I "tested this". I wanted to learn about threading and stuff inside Qt and I was a really terrible programming (just started my graduation course) so I played (a lot!) with this terrible stuff. I agree with you, this is really bad advice, but I managed to make it work once, and with the details the user gave there is not too much to be said.

Comment: The problem is that your code running without crashing for any length of time is not an indication that it works. There is no way to *test* that it works. Test results, outside of very narrow circumstances, can't be taken as an indication of a lack of bugs, they can only be used to indicate presence of bugs when tests fail. A properly designed test **will always fail** when you construct `QWidget` in non-gui threads. It's only a matter of writing such a test.